# Is it possible to acquire an SSH authorized RSA private key just by having access to the server?

Tags: ssh, authorized-keys

Is it possible to get hold of an RSA private key (pem file) simply by having (root) access to a server that authorizes ssh access using that that private key. For example, can the entries in `.ssh/authorized_keys` be used to generated the RSA private keys for which they are associated with.

The reason I ask is because I need to disable ssh access to a server with a particular key file. I've edited the `authorized_keys` file manually and removed the entry associated with that key. That worked and ssh access is no longer possible with that key file, but before I did that, I had created a new private key for ssh access.

I'm concerned that someone with that disabled key file may have been able to acquire the new RSA private key before I was able to delete the old one.

Is that possible?

Comment: Already over http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/99669/is-it-possible-to-acquire-an-ssh-authorized-rsa-private-key-just-by-having

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For practical purposes:  no, it's not possible.  More strictly speaking:  it's possible, but not feasible.  The attacker would need immense computing power or major mathematical breakthroughs.

The entry in your `authorized_keys` file is a public key.  The *whole point* of public-key cryptography is that your public key can be public because an attacker can't use it to derive your private key.